# Java adding series of fractions together

Tags: java, double, fractions

So, I have a question in my assignment. It's "Add fractions (1/10)+(2/9)+(3/8)+(4/7)+(5/6)+(6/5)+(7/4)+(8/3)+(9/2)+(10/1) together and the output should be 4 decimal points". I've written a loop using 1 and 10 value increasing and decreasing as I go. It doesn't seem to be coming up with the correct answer. It should be 22.218650... etc because I haven't limited the decimal places yet, but it doesn't give the correct answer. The output I'm getting is 18.0.

```
public class AddThemUp {
  // instance variables - replace the example below with your own

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    int i;
    int numer = 1;
    int denom = 10;
    double addUp = 0.0;

    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        addUp = (numer / denom) + addUp;
        numer++;
        denom--;
    }
    System.out.println(addUp);
  }
}
```

The addUp println is just to see if the math is working properly before I try and figure out the decimal place delimiter. Am I using the double improperly or should the numer and denom be double as well? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing int division which *always* returns an int -- not the result you want. You need to do *double division* for this to work. Cast the numerator or denominator of the fraction to double:

```
((double) numerator / denominator)
```

Comment: Excellent! Knew I was missing something with the operation. Thanks a bunch. Would it work if the numer and denom were double to begin with?

Comment: @user1588867: then your for loop could get messed up. Best to leave that which is naturally an int as an int, and convert to double when you need to.

Comment: Thanks. Changed it and it works now. Just used the DecimalFormat class and prints everything properly now.

Answer (score 1):

Its converting your division (`numer/denom`) to `int` **so all decimal values in the result are lost**. Convert one of the value to decimal e.g. `double` in your computation e.g. below:

```
 addUp = ((double)numer / denom) + addUp;
```

You will get your expected result.